# SQL query to get "vote score"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My `votes` table looks like this:

```
id: integer
vote: boolean
voteable_id: integer
voteable_type: string
voter_id: integer
voter_type: string
```

The `vote` column determines whether the row represents an "up vote" (`vote = true`) or a "down vote" (`vote = false`).

`voteable_type` is the class of the thing being voted on, `voteable_id` is the id of the thing being voted on, `voter_type` is the class of the voter, and `voter_id` is the id of the voter.

What I need is a query to get the top *n* `posts` in descending order by **"vote score"**, where "vote score" is defined as (the number of up votes the post has) - (the number of down votes the post has).

Bonus points if your solution doesn't require me to resort to `find_by_sql()` (I'm working in Rails)

More bonus points if your solution works the same way in SQLite and PostgreSQL (though it's more important that it work in PostgreSQL).

Comment: You would also make your life much much easier if you stored this as 1/-1 instead of true/false as well.

Answer (score 3):

Generically, you can do it by using a [`case`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-conditional.html) statement with a [`sum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select
    voteable_id,
    sum(case
        when vote then 1
        else -1
    end) as vote_score
from
    votes
group by
    voteable_id
```

Note that this is ANSI SQL, so will work across SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, etc., etc.

To get your top N posts, you would simply append to the above query:

```
order by
    vote_score desc
limit 10
```

`limit` is used by Postgres and SQLite (a bit differently in MySQL), and not in Oracle or SQL Server, as an FYI.

So, to get the posts info associated with this:

```
select
    p.title,
    p.author,
    p.createdate,
    sum(case
            when v.vote then 1
            else -1
        end) as vote_score
from
    posts p
    inner join votes v on
        p.post_id = v.voteable_id
group by
    p.title,
    p.author,
    p.createdate
order by
    vote_score desc
limit 10
```

Comment: Now add the top N requirement too?

Comment: Cool -- how would I then add a `join` into the mix to get the `posts` associated with the returned `voteable_id`s?

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that second query I get `SQL error: near "sum": syntax error`

Comment: the last query didn't have `group by`, d'oh!

Answer (score 2):

The conditional function common to SQLite and PostgreSQL (and other ANSI-compliant SQL implementations) is `CASE` -- see e.g. [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) for PostgreSQL and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) for SQLite. So the inner part for "count +1 / -1 number of votes" is going to have to be

```
SUM(CASE WHEN vote THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
```

and you'll also inevitably need a `GROUP BY voteable_id` to make this `SUM` work right.

This will need to be in the `ORDER BY` for the sorting (with a DESC); not sure if you ALSO want it in the results, but I'll assume you do, in which case it also needs to be in the `SELECT` (and you can refer to its alias in the `ORDER BY`).  Finally, `LIMIT n` works in both engines.

So, putting it all together:

```
  SELECT voteable_id,
         SUM(CASE WHEN vote THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS vote_score
  FROM votes
  GROUP BY voteable_id
  ORDER BY vote_score DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

should satisfy all of your requirements.

Comment: Cool -- how would I then add a `join` into the mix to get the `posts` associated with the returned `voteable_id`s?

Comment: between FROM and GROUP BY, add `JOIN posts USING(voteable_id)` (if that's the field name on both tables, otherwise use an `ON` condition) and in the SELECT pick the needed fields from `posts.`; also make sure to disambiguate `votes.voteable_id` etc as needed (explicit qualification of fields is recommended when > 1 table is involved!-).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VoteFu (which it looks like you are), then I'd recommend that you convert to using Integers to store the vote values instead of :boolean.

The only reason that votes in VoteFu are stored as booleans is that I felt I needed to maintain backward compatibility with Acts_As_Voteable. I've now decided that I placed too much weight on this concern.

I'm going to be releasing a new version of the VoteFu plugin that handles the conversion for you, but until then I think changing this yourself is a smart move.  Here's how:

```
class VoteFuIntegerMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up  
    add_column :votes, :vote_int, :integer
    Vote.find(:all).each do |vote|
       vote.vote_int = vote.vote? ? 1 : -1
       vote.save!
    end
    remove_column :vote, :vote
    rename_column :vote, :vote_int, :vote
  end
end
```

And then:

```
module Juixe 
  module Acts   
    module Voteable   
      module InstanceMethods  
        def votes_for  
          Vote.sum(:vote, :conditions => [  
            "voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ? AND vote > 0",  
            id, self.class.name])  
        end  

        def votes_against  
          Vote.sum(:vote, :conditions => [  
            "voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ? AND vote < 0",  
            id, self.class.name])  
        end  

        def votes_total  
          Vote.sum(:vote, :conditions => [  
            "voteable_id = ? AND voteable_type = ?",  
            id, self.class.name])  
        end  
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It's probably a good idea to introduce the module changes as a monkeypatch. The new VoteFu will have this code integrated (with tests, too.)

Comment: Any progress on the next version, Pete? (I'm still loving your gem!)

Comment: I have been horribly, terribly remiss in coding my next version! A couple other project usurped me. I'm currently looking for other committers to help out. If you want to submit a patch from your solution that does the integer conversion stuff, I'd be happy to 1) credit you fully and b) make you a committer on the project. Lemme know!